# Iphone, callback and objective c

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, callback

I am using a c++ library using callback to inform about the progress of an operation.
Everything is working fine except this:
I need to have a function in my controller to be use as a c++ callback function.
I've tried a lot of things but none of them are working.

Do you know how we can manage this kind of thing?

Thanks :)

Comment: More specifics, please: What approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a c++-class in your .h with your callback methods, implementing the c++-interface. This class also keeps a delegate of your objC Class.

in your .m File after @end you specify the c++ methods. You may then use the delegate to perform selectors of your objC class

in .h

```
@interface YourObjcClass {
#ifdef __cplusplus
    class FooObserver : public YourNS::Interface {
    public:
        virtual ~FooObserver() {
        }
        YourObjcClass *delegate;
        };
YourNS::YourCallbackClass *myCallbackClass;
#endif
```

in .m

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
void FooObserver::callback( args ) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performCallback) 
                   withObject:nil 
                waitUntilDone:false];
[pool release];
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

iPhone APIs like the Audio Queue Services use a `void *` parameter in their callbacks, into which you can stuff your Objective-C instance.

If your C++ library has a similar setup - your callback gives a `void *` "context" parameter - you could do this:

```
void interruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruptionState) {
  InterruptionMonitor *self = (InterruptionMonitor *)inClientData;
  [self inInterruption: inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption];
}
```

So you use the inClientData to store your instance, and can then call methods on that instance that do the actual processing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much better way of doing this. If you are already using boost in your iOS project you can use my objc_callback template: http://alex.tapmania.org/2012/04/c-to-obj-c-callbacks-part-2.html